How to fix the error "Connection Failed ... Could not connect to the GlobalProtect service"?
I use Palo Alto Networks GlobalProtect VPN on Windows 10. It complains the GlobalProtect service is stopped. But I don't see any GlobalProtect service:

How can I start the GlobalProtect service?

It also happens on Windows 11 from time to time. When it happens, all subsequent attempts by clicking Connect are failing.

The GlobalProtect service is called "PanGPS" (stands for "Palo Alto Networks GlobalProtect service"):

